# Описание какой ошибки было под номером 5 в $_FILES['pic']['error']?

Tags: php, fileupload, обработка-ошибок

Описание какой ошибки было под номером **5** тут http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.errors.php в

```
 $_FILES['pic']['error']
```

Думаю что когда-то было, воможно в древних версиях php?

Comment: А это очень важно?

Comment: ДА. ДЛЯ МЕНЯ ЭТО ВАЖНО!!! Я ХОЧУ ЗНАТЬ! А вы наверное никогда не задавались таким вопросом?

Comment: Если бы он имел хоть какую-то мало мальски важную применимость на практике - да. Однако знание того, что там было в константах на пятом месте, а что на сорок пятом - не прибавляет никакого смысла к разработке. Это всё равно, что было в неком здании строгое расписание в туалете: вторник с 2 до 4, а сейчас — пятница с 3 до 5 и вам ну ооооооочень важно знать, почему по вторникам было. Лично мне важно знать какое в настоящее  время действующее расписание. Так что вопрос исторический, а не практический  и отсюда — бессмысленный

Comment: ну а мне просто интересно. разве приобретение, пополнение знаний и опыта на этом ресурсе не приветствуется?

Comment: SO — для решения практических проблем и наполнение практическими приемами, а не экскурсы в историю....Как бесполезная информация помогла/поможет набрать вам практический опыт и применить это на практике — без понятия.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что является экскурсом в историю, а не **конкретной прикладной повседневной и АКТУАЛЬНОЙ** задачей, которая встретится в жизни и понадобится при разработке. Данное знание не применить на практике и не является практической проблемой, а значит бесполезно для остальных посетителей.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я бы оставил этот вопрос, так как история языка программирования важна 1. для поддержки legacy-кода. 2. даёт понимание почему язык сейчас существует именно в таком виде.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov `...история языка программирования...` — вот именно. **экскурс в историю**. Спасибо, что еще раз подтвердили мои слова....`даёт понимание почему язык сейчас существует именно в таком виде` — всё является **экскурсом в историю**. Для этого есть специальные книги и ресурсы. Вопрос — непотребен.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А аргумент про legacy код?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вы серьезно полагаете, что еще кто-то поддерживает на плаву серьезные сайты с версией ниже 4.3, а не пользуют версии без существенных дыр в безопасности? Серьезно? Точно? Давайте по статистике: в инете сайтов свыше 1млрд 200млн. Из них 82.4% на PHP. Из этого процента только 0.8% занимают PHP4, а из этого процента 98% занимают сайты с PHP  >= 4.3. Если вы во владах с математикой — вы посчитаете этот ничтожный плевок в океан. Из них еще учесть, что б**О**льшая часть — зарубеж. Надеюсь вы не скажите, что кто-то еще и Netscape Navigator использует? Так что всё это давно история.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov максимум что сейчас на такой древней версии поддерживается — сайтики визитки, где никакие file upload вообще не требуется.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давным-давно, в далёкой-далёкой галактике код под номером 5 [существовал](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/6083eb1030182419aea0dd943bdd93cdf7c1fa71).

```
#define UPLOAD_ERROR_E  5  /* Uploaded file size 0 bytes */
```

Добавлен 24 ноября 2001 и обозначал код ошибки на тот случай, если был загружен файл нулевой длины. При этом вдобавок генерировался `E_WARNING`. Суровый PHP начала тысячелетия, мда.

Через полгодика [люди одумались](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/19b7861d70a79417797a6f8ebc0d74133d75bfeb), и выпилили эту фигню. Файлы нулевого размера стало можно загружать и уже PHP-код приложения мог посмотреть в параметр `size` и решить самостоятельно, нравится ему такой файл или нет.

Интересно, что в PHP-коде константы с таким значением никогда не существовало. Для PHP кода эти [константы](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/ed58d3a235883fc56d84499fab7b5b02d69a704e) появились уже после этой истории и изначально не имели кода 5. Этот коммит вошёл в `PHP 4.3.0`. На всякий случай значение 5 было пропущено при добавлении и [последующих констант](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/f41c40f63e8716bd2a05aaf89071453f3d8c8128).

Answer (score 2):

Константы из шторма. 5 отсутствует.

```
define ('UPLOAD_ERR_OK', 0);
define ('UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE', 1);
define ('UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE', 2);
define ('UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL', 3);
define ('UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE', 4);
define ('UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR', 6);
define ('UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE', 7);
define ('UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION', 8);
```

Удалось нагуглить

```
5 | UPLOAD_ERROR_E        | As expliained by @Progman, removed in rev.  81792
```